# How to get a slice 2D array by list of rows in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array and I need to get another 2D array with the selected rows.

This is for a recommendation engine where I have performed a Singualar Value Decomposition and now I need to get only some especific rows from the U matrix. I have the index of those rows but I don't know how to "reshape" that matrix based on the index rows.

To make it easier I indicate below what I want to do with a basic example.

```
IN

a=np.diag(np.arange(14))

rows=np.array([0,3,5])
```

```
OUT

#expected output

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

​Any support on it?

Comment: So you could just index `a` with `a[rows]`...?

Comment: yes, you are right.